# Projectable contact vector fields of projective cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space, contact-geometry

Consider the projective cotangent bundle $PT^\star M$ with the contact structure inherited from the kernel of the Liouville form of $T^\star M$. A contact vector field $X$ (infinitesimal contactomorphism) on $PT^\star M$ can locally be the Reeb field $E$ of a contact form $\omega$, and there is always a coordinate system on $PT^\star M$ such that $\omega = dx^0 - y_i dx^i$ locally ($i=1..n$; Einstein summation convention). In this coordinate system, $E$ is $\partial/\partial x^0$. Now, $x^0$ and $x^i$ can be pulled-back coordinates from the base $M$ to the bundle, and therefore $E$ projects to the vector field $\partial/\partial x^0$ on $M$. Do these show that any contact vector field $X$ on $PT^\star M$ is always projectable locally to a vector field $\pi_\star X$ on $M$ (by the projection $\pi:PT^\star M \rightarrow M$), or am I confused about something here?

**P.S.**: Why do I think $x^0$ and $x^i$ could be pulled-back from $M$?
It is because $T^\star M$ can be given coordinates $x^0$, $x^i$, $p_0$, $p_i$, where $x^0$ and $x^i$ are on $M$, and the restriction of $dx^0 + p_i/p_0 dx^i$ ($p_0 \neq 0$) to $PT^\star M$, obtained from the Liouville form on $T^\star M$, is a contact form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d} \newcommand{\dx}{\d \!}$
Consider $T^2\times S^1$, which is naturally isomorphic as a circle bundle to the projective cotangent bundle $PT^*(T^2)$ of the $2$-torus $T^2$.
The canonical contact form of $PT^*(T^2)$ reads $\cos\theta \dx x + \sin \theta \dx y$ (it is claimed in [this article](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article-abstract/1996/2/77/766629), for instance), whose Reeb vector field $\cos \theta\, \partial_x + \sin\theta\, \partial_y$ is tautologically a contact vector field, but does not project onto the base $T^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. $M$ is $n+1$ dimensional ($PT^\star M$ is $2n+1$ dimensional). I get your point, but your coordinates are not of the type I mentioned and it does not clear my confusion. I don't have access to the article. I edited the post. Maybe it clarifies why I think $x^0$ and $x^i$ could be pulled-back from the base.

Comment: @Meem What I showed is that the Reeb vector field of the canonical contact form (obtained from the Liouville form) of $PT^*(T^2)$ won't project on the torus, independently of the chosen coordinates.
So I think that it completely answers your question.
You're right for the dimension. Finally, let me remind you that it is forbidden and highly not advised to look for articles on some websites like one starting with sci and ending in hub :)

Comment: @Meem Being projectable, being the Reeb vector field, *etc.* do not depend of the chosen coordinates. Pick your favourite Darboux coordinates for $PT^*(T^2)$, this will lead to the same conclusion.

Comment: You're a good person and I appreciate your advise about not using harmful websites:). I know coordinates do not matter. The point is that I'm not sure it is the same contact structure. I don't understand how $x^0$ is not pulled back. What goes wrong when the contact form is expressed as $dx^0 - y_i dx^i$?

Comment: You're basically right. The contact structure inherited from the Liouville form can be determined by various contact forms and not all of them can be constructed by pullback coordinates in the way explained in the post, just some of them. (That said, I'm still not sure your mentioned form represents the same contact structure. I'll think about it. Thank you for your help.)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Didier, $x^0$ as a Darboux coordinate is not necessarily pulled back from the base $M$. The point that I was missing is that not all contact forms representing the same contact structure on $PT^\star M$ (inherited from the kernel of the Liouville form of $T^\star M$) have to be in the form $dx^0 - y_i dx^i$ where $x^0$ and $x^i$ are pulled back from $M$. A form $h(dx^0 - y_i dx^i)$, where $h=h(x^0, x^i, y_i)$, represents the same contact structure, and the Darboux coordinates of the latter do not have to be pulled-back in general.